# Generating a locale causes system breakdown

Tags: linux, debian

I generated a locale (by uncommenting locale for Polish lang - "pl_PL ISO-8859-2" and running `locale-gen`). After that my system broke down. I can't boot to my Gnome GUI (the system freezes with black screen); moreover can't type some letters (e.g. "o" or "m") so I can't even log to system in command line mode. Can I restore default settings using a Debian live CD and if so how do I do it?

Comment: You may want to try rebuilding the locale database.  i.e. mv /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive.tmpl; build-locale-archive

Comment: "build-locale-archive" - command not found. BTW should i run it from live cd?

Comment: Sorry, debian is a bit different.  Take a look [at this link](https://people.debian.org/~schultmc/locales.html) and treat it as a missing  /etc/locale.gen   You may also want to make note of their warning in the comment section about manually editing.

Comment: Ok, so i've to run live cd, mount my debian partition and then run locale-gen from mounted dir (eg /mnt/sda1/usr/sbin)? Will it work?

Comment: I would expect you would have to chroot to /mnt/sda1 first

Comment: Ok thx. I would try...